# Magento - Add 'Customer Account Navigation' to custom module page

Tags: module, magento-1, custom

I have a custom module in my magento store. It is currently using the default 2 column layout with magento's left nav as the lefthand sidebar.

How can i go about having the customer account navigation in my left sidebar instead? My current xml file for my module is:

earnings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <earnings_index_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="earnings/earnings" name="earnings" />
        </reference>
    </earnings_index_index>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use the  XML function

```
<earnings_index_index translate="label">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
    <reference name="my.account.wrapper">
        <block type="core/template" name="earnings" template="earnings/earnings.phtml" />
    </reference>
</earnings_index_index>
```

To change the default title within your controller you'll need to place

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('Title here'));
```

Withing your **loadLayout()** and **renderLayout()** calls, such as:

```
$this->loadLayout()
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('Title here'));
$this->renderLayout();
```

Comment: Thanks Dave but when i do the above my earnings page now shows the account navigation but not the earnings.phtml. Turning on template path hints shows the phtml file is not being shown/loaded

Comment: @odd_duck does your block earnings/earnings contain a setTemplate call?

Comment: Had another look at this and managed to get it working by changing the block type to `<block type="core/template" name="earnings" template="earnings/earnings.phtml" />` instead so probably what you were mentioning? Thank you so much. One last thing - how would i go about setting the page title for this page in the above?

Comment: @odd_duck I've updated my original answer with how to change the title.

Comment: @odd_duck no problem!

Answer (score 0):

Below are the snippet on adding link to left navigation in my account section.

```
<customer_account translate="label">        
            <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
                <action method="addLink" translate="label"><name>nameoflink</name><path>path/index/index/</path><label>Custom Account Link</label></action>
            </reference>
        </customer_account>
```

Comment: I don't want to add a link to the navigation, i want to add the navigation to a page

Comment: please check what you have asked. i think you have not specified in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a page layout using `root` block. Here is the code that you need to try

```
<earnings_index_index>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-right.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
         <reference name="content">
             <!-- put content blocks here -->
         </reference>
</earnings_index_index>
```

Take a look on the section `root` block. This block is use to set layout template that need to use while render the page. Here it is set to `2columns-right.phtml`. This template allow navigation section in the right side. Take a look at `app/design/frontend/<pockage>/<theme>/template/page/` directory. There you can see page layout template files that are use to constitute the page structure. You can use any of those layout files by specifying there name in `root` block.